# bash commands that don't fit on one page - make output scrollable

Tags: linux, bash

Probably been answered somewhere, but its difficult to frame the search phrase.

I am running a bash terminal window and some commands are too big to fit on the page (e.g. `ps -A`)

I vaguely recall a command line parameter / method that shows the command output page by page so I can scroll through the output, but I can't recall what it is.... any pointers?

Comment: `ps -A | less` or `ps -A | more`? There's also `ps -A | vim -` or `ps | gvim -` for the fans of vim.

Comment: with _shift up_ usually you can scroll up your terminal and read...

Comment: @CristianCiupitu That's the one! - less/more, thanks :)

Comment: @Hastur Normally, yes, the terminal used has a buffer you can scroll, but I am using this on a really really basic terminal (seems to be from the 60's), there is no scroll/buffer. :(

Comment: If you have `less` it's somehow better than `more`: you can scroll easily up and down, it's able to see if the file/stream is binary and to prompt before showing it (In this case you avoid to mess the character set of your screen with an uncontrolled _binary text_) :-).

Comment: @Hastur yeah, I found that with more, once you get to the end of the text it drops out, less does not :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For commands I use often, I generally set up a `function` in my **.bashrc** to make them paginate if longer than a screen.

Like your example: (ps -A)

```
function ps { command ps "$@" |& less -F; }
```

This replaces `ps` with a function, named `ps`, which calls the original `ps` command with whatever arguments given on the command line, then pipes the output (stdout **and** stderr, using the `|&` pipe) into `less -F`, which pauses if there's more than a screen-full, but exits immediately if it's less than a screen-full.

VERY handy, doesn't interfere with anything I've worked with so far, and is just cool!

You can even add oft-used options into the command/functions too:

```
function nm { command nm --demangle "$@" |& less -F; }
```

This makes `nm` always demangle C++ symbols.  **AND** paginates the output.  Yay!

I'm running **Debian**, so I use the `apt-cache` command quite often, *search* and *show* mostly.  This function causes those particular options to paginate, *search* output is sorted, and everything paginates:

```
function apt-cache { case  "$1" in "search") command apt-cache "$@" | sort | less -F;; *) command apt-cache "$@" | less -F;; esac; }
```

If the command is 'search', sort the output, then paginate with `less -F`, but if command is anything else, just paginate, without sorting.

Occasionally I forget I've got the functions, and I'll do something like:

```
apt-cache search gcc | less
```

The function doesn't interfere, everything works as expected, no harm either way.

Another little tweak, I use the same `.bashrc` on all my systems, so sometimes a utility might not be installed, so there's no need for the function.  I make them conditional like this:

```
which apt-cache &>/dev/null && function apt-cache { case  "$1" in "search") command apt-cache "$@" |& sort | less -F;; *) command apt-cache "$@" |& less -F;; esac; }
```

This just uses the `which` command to determine if a program is available, if it isn't, it quietly fails and skips installing the function.  Taa Daa!

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating `command`, which I've always needed. Now I can actually redefine the builtin to have a nice function wrapping the real builtin!

Comment: +1 agree with bgStack... though I think for my issue, less will do :)

Answer (score 10):

The normal method is to pipe the output to "less".

```
ls -R / | less
```

<kbd>q</kbd> is the key to quit, just like a man page.

If the command may produce errors or other output to stderr you may want to direct that to the pipe as well.

```
ls -R 2>&1 | less
```

Any machine that has bash should have less as well.  On old Linux machines the program was **more**, but that does just a page at a time, **less** will allow you to scroll as you wish.

Comment: "q is the key to quit, just like a man page". That's because the output of the **man** command is piped to a *pager* like **less** or **more**, but if no pager is configured or a different one if used, the **q** key might not work.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the output to 'more'

```
output | more -d


Enter - > Scroll by line
Space - > Scroll by Page
q     - > Quit
```

Tested on rpm based OS.