# How to stop Bash terminal erasing anything more than one page (Ubuntu on Windows 10)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bash, terminal, history

I'm new so apologies for breaking any of the question rules.

Bash is removing any command line inputs and outputs that goes off the terminal window, that is, I can't scroll up to view +~30 commands ago, or if there is a long output from the machine it goes off the screen and is now gone forever.

Before, a scroll bar would appear on the right hand side where I could look at previous I/Os. Now, there is one page of I/Os and anything before that is inaccessible. It is like writing a google doc but whenever you add to it the top of the document disappears.

Has anyone seen this before and if so, how do I make it stop?

Not sure it's the same as this question [bash commands that don't fit on one page - make output scrollable](https://superuser.com/questions/775941/bash-commands-that-dont-fit-on-one-page-make-output-scrollable)
up until this morning I was scrolling away happily through lines of 'history'

Cheers.

If you feel that the posted answer(s) do not address your issue, then describe as clearly as you can how your computer’s behavior has changed — what you were able to do before today that you can’t do now?  Do you mean just looking at previous commands, or do you mean their output?  How were you “scrolling away happily”? Please do not respond in comments; edit your question to make it clearer and more complete.  If you’re satisfied with the answer(s) you’ve gotten, never min

Comment: If you feel that the posted answer(s) do not address your issue, then describe as clearly as you can how your computer’s behavior has changed — what you were able to do before today that you can’t do now?  Do you mean just looking at previous *commands*, or do you mean their output?  *How* were you “scrolling away happily”? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  If you’re satisfied with the answer(s) you’ve gotten, never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much you can scroll back doesn't depend on bash itself but on the settings of the terminal window. Most of the output you see isn't from bash but from the commands started by bash (and bash doesn't see any of it)

If you expect a large output from a command you can pipe it to `more` or to `less` (`less` allows you to scroll back and forth):

```
some_command | less
```

or to a file and then edit the file:

```
some_command >command.log
```

By default you only get the standard output that way, error message still go directly to the terminal, if you want to catch the error messages as well, reroute the stderr stream to stdout:

```
some_command >command.log 2>&1
```

It is also useful to filter the output with `grep` to only display the parts you are interested in:

```
some_command | grep "Warning:"
```

You can recall commands you issued using "Cursor Up".

Comment: Sorry for the poorly phrased question, this isn't per command basis but all the previous I/Os of the terminal window.

Comment: I understand your question... But the answer isn't with bash, but with the application that runs bash and maintains a virtual terminal in a window to show bash output. It usually has a setting for this (in my desktop, looks like this: [Setting](https://i.imgur.com/pfo3qNL.png). In a real terminal there is no native scrolling support, even if there is a `screen` command that adds one. But as you get skilled, you learn to limit the output (instead of scrolling and searching, recall the command and add a `grep` to it).

Comment: Ah! I found it. Settings -> Layout -> Window buffer size.
Thanks for the help, this was driving me crazy